# FLUTTER - Aplicación deja de funcionar al pasar a app-release.apk, no reconoce librería externa usada en parte nativa android

Tags: android-studio, flutter, apk, jar

llevo unas horas enfrentándome a un problema en Flutter relacionado con librerías externas.
He heredado una app desarrollada en Flutter por una empresa externa, la app básicamente hace lecturas RFID con terminales ITOS de Android (Modelo IC-51).
Para poder hacer estas lecturas RFID flutter se comunica con la parte nativa a través de BasicMessageChannel.MessageHandler y esta incluye una librería externa .jar
La app cuando esta en DEBUG o PROFILE funciona perfecta, cuando construyo la RELEASE apk para subir la app a Google Play la construye bien. La app inicia y todo correcto, pero al hacer una lectura RFID que entonces entra en juego la librería la app se para y deja de funcionar.

Que estoy haciendo mal? he probado hasta hacer un downgrade al sdk de flutter.
Mi Flutter doctor:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19042.985], locale es-ES)
• Flutter version 2.0.5 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision adc687823a (5 weeks ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
• Engine revision b09f014e96
• Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\raul.felez\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• IC 51 (mobile) • IC51000287 • android-arm64  • Android 7.1.1 (API 25)
• Chrome (web)   • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
• Edge (web)     • edge       • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 84.0.522.52

• No issues found!

Totalmente clavado en estos momentos ;D

Comment: Lo más seguro es que necesitas alguna configuración de proguard para la ofuscación , leiste las instrucciones del plugin?  También viendo los logs te ayudaría a detectar el error.
Sería bueno que indiques que librerías usas.  te invito -> youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, teóricamente proguard es para reducir el tamaño del APK o proteger ese código de ingeniería inversa. No entiendo porque puede venir por ahí el problema. No tengo nada de documentación de la librería, solo la librería en si...

Comment: Algunos plugins tienen la indicación de que agregas unas líneas en proguard para evitar la ofuscación de ciertas clases, para que puedan ser leídas de forma correcta, por eso te digo, revisa las instrucciones del plugin.

Comment: El error que me aparece en consola cuando lanzo flutter run --release es:  E/AndroidRuntime(18349): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
E/AndroidRuntime(18349): Process: com.winfor.re_food, PID: 18349
E/AndroidRuntime(18349): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void b.b.a.d.a.a(b.b.a.d.b)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(18349):        at com.winfor.re_food.MainActivity.p()
E/AndroidRuntime(18349):        at com.winfor.re_food.MainActivity.k()
E/AndroidRuntime(18349):        at com.winfor.re_food.MainActivity$b.run()

Comment: si, parece relacionado a lo que comenté ,  revisa el plugin que usas, las instrucciones, los issues abiertos, y encontrarás la respuesta.

Comment: Solución perfecta @diegovelopor!! Muchisimas gracias de verdad, menudo crack estas hecho ;D

Comment: genial, que plugin estabas usando por cierto?

Comment: Plugin UHF que es de ITOS una marca de dispositivos que usan RFID para hacer lecturas de tags

Comment: en mi caso el error es Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'F:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1